# Валидация массива Laravel: наличие минимум одного смивола в значении

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Всем привет!
Из формы приходит массив вида:

```
array: [
  "specializations" => array: [
    0 => ""
    1 => ""
    2 => ""
    3 => ""
  ]
]
```

Как можно проверить валидацией заполненность хотя бы одного значения в массиве?
Т.е. массив ниже не должен вызывать ошибки:

```
array: [
  "specializations" => array: [
    0 => ""
    1 => "12"
    2 => ""
    3 => ""
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Решение такое:**

1. Создаем свое правило
   `php artisan make:rule CheckArray`
2. В метод passes добавляем проверку

   ```
   public function passes($attribute, $value)
   {
       foreach($value as $v) if((int)$v > 0) return true ;
   }
   ```
3. В контроллере валидация выглядит таким образом:

   ```
   $validate_fields = $request->validate([
       ...
       'name' => 'required|min:3',
       'specializations' => new CheckArray,
       'cities' => ['required', new CheckArray],
       ...
   ]) ;
   ```